# Importing modules with variable paths?

Tags: python

I have dev and production systems.

My production system is different from my dev system in that that it adds one directory to the beginning path.

for eg. on dev system:

main->module1->module2

becomes on production:

project_name->main->module1->module2.

Because of that I have to change all my imports to accommodate for this change.

I wanted to make settings file in the main folder and include it in every file and call exec("import %s.modulexxx" % path).

But the problem is how to access settings file (because I also need to know my directory path).

Is there a way to include some file below, for eg. :

if it is main->module1->module2 , in module2 I could include ../../settings.py
so if it changes to project_name->main->module1->module2 it would still work because it would still be 2 level below.

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just modify `sys.path` to include the directory one level down? Then the same imports will work in both places.